# Convert Fraction to decimal number and sort them

Tags: c++, sorting

I want to sort rational numbers into ascending order so I tried to convert the numbers into decimal and sort them. I have done the part of converting to decimals but I have no clue on how to continue after this part to sort the decimals.

For example: 1/3, 5/3, 7/2, 1/2
Output: 1/2, 1/3, 5/3, 7/2

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
private:
    float numer = 0.0f;
    float denom = 0.0f;

public:
    Fraction(int numer, int denom);
    ~Fraction();
    void setNum(int NumInput) 
    { 
        numer = NumInput; 
    };
    int getNum() 
    { 
        return numer; 
    };
    void setDem(int DemInput) 
    { 
        denom = DemInput; 
    };
    int getDem() 
    { 
        return denom; 
    };

    float getDec()
    {
        return numer / denom;
    };
};

Fraction::Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    numer = numerator;
    denom = denominator;
}

Fraction::~Fraction()
{

}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Fraction a1(2, 3);
    Fraction a2(7, 2);
    Fraction a3(6, 7);
    Fraction a4(27, 4);
}
```

Comment: You can probably write your own sorting algorithm, or try to use std::sort  (under algorithm header) with a custom function for comparing. There's an example of how to implement that here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: You can define the `<` operator for your class `Fraction`, and the use `std::sort` directly. A side point: why are you using `float` and not `int` for the numerator and the denominator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to convert to decimal to compare 2 fractions. If you have a/b and c/d then just compare `a*d` and `b*c`

```
bool operator<(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right)
{
    return (double)left.getNum()*right.getDem < (double)left.getDem()*right.getNum();
}
```

This is more correct than comparing the decimal value because it avoids the rounding after dividing 2 numbers. Besides it's also faster because multiplication is a lot faster than division. Once you have the compare function or `operator<` then you can sort them with `std::sort()`. Also make the `get` functions `const` so that the compiler won't reevaluate the values each time you call it as stefan said

Note that it's better to define numerators and denominators as *integers* instead of float as commented above, because floating-point types are actually fractions under the hood, although with a more restricted range of denominators

You also need *sign normalization* to make this work. You can choose to always set either the numerator or denominator as negative for negative fractions. Alternatively you can normalize when comparing them like this

```
int dem = (long long)left.getNum()*right.getDem - left.getDem()*right.getNum();
if (right.getDem() < 0) dem = -dem;
if (left.getDem() < 0) dem = -dem;
return (dem > 0) - (dem < 0);
```

Comment: The right way effectively. A side note: why not using a *friend* operator, to directly access the private numbers? No risk as variables are declared as constant

Comment: @Damien yes, you can even make a public member operator. I just copied the definition from stefan's answer instead of retyping it

Answer (score 1):

First, make your getXXX functions constant and then implement a comparison operator like this

```
bool operator<(const Fraction& left, const Fraction& right)
{
    return left.getDec() < right.getDec();
}
```

and then use std::sort() on a collection of Fractions as suggested above.

And you will have to change the getDec() function to prevent division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to point out that in converting rational fractions to decimals, there will be loss of accuracy due to size limits of the datatype you are using.

If, say, the first 15 digits after the decimal are same, then your program will be unable to find the greater of the two numbers and hence, fail to sort them.

Example:

`111 111 111 111 111 3 / 1 000 000 000 000 000 0`

`111 111 111 111 111 7 / 1 000 000 000 000 000 0`

I'd recommend a **different approach**  :

1. Take both numerator and denominator as long/ largest possible integer type.
2. Find the LCM of all denominators.
3. Multiply each numerator by ( LCM / respective denominator ).
4. Sort the fractions according to their numerators.

Comment: Note: phuclv 's approach is more efficient than mine.