# Divide without divide c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

There is a problem I am supposed to solve that is normally easy, but it has a catch.

There are 2 types of candy. One type weighs `m1` kg and is sold for `s1` Euro. A second type weighs `m2` kg and is sold for `s2` Euro. All numbers are integers.

The question is, which type of candy costs more per kg?

The catch is, you can't use divide operation at all, neither `/` nor `%`.

For example, if we have the numbers as `m1`=2, `s1`=17, `m2`=3, and `s2`=14 then the answer needs to be that the first candies are more expensive as 17/2=8.5 and 14/3=4.(3).

As I am a C++ student, I am restricted to use only that which has been taught so far in the class to determine the more expensive candy. The only thing we learned so far was `+` `-` `/` `*` `%` and `if` statement with `else`. Also `==` `>` `<` `&&` `||`.

Comment: You could just use `div` which returns the quotient and remainder in a structure. But I assume you'e not meant to do that.

Comment: Assuming both values are positive, try repeated subtraction.

Comment: And the only thing we learned so far was + - / * % and if function with else. And == > < &&, ||

Comment: Can you use for and while?

Comment: No you can't as we haven't learned it yet. I know how to use it but the teacher says you need to do only if we learned it in class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Fraction to decimal number and sort them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62549344/convert-fraction-to-decimal-number-and-sort-them)

Comment: duplicate: [Comparing fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23177522/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare *X* ≡ `s1 * m2` with *Y* ≡ `s2 * m1`. If *X* > *Y*, then `s1 / m1` > `s2 / m2`.

No division is required to do the comparison.

<sub><sup>The caveat to this solution is that `s1`, `s2`, `m1`, and `m2` should all have the same sign, and `m1` and `m2` should be non-zero.</sup></sub>

---

Let's assume all the values are positive integers (hence, greater than 0). Consequently `m1 * m2` is positive as well. Let *z* be the number such that:

> *z* + (`s1 / m1`) = `s2 / m2`

By multiplying by `m1 * m2` on both sides, we get:

> *z'* + (`s1 * m2`) = `s2 * m1` ∵ *z'* ≡ *z* × (`m1 * m2`)

Since *z* and *z'* have the same sign, the relational order of `s1 / m1` and `s1 / m2` is the same as the relational order of `s1 * m2` and `s2 * m1`.

Comment: One should also check that `m1 > 0` and `m2 > 0`.

Comment: @StephanLechner Yes, there are edge cases. Answer not fully specified since it appears to be homework.